# SQL SUM() Calculates only one row in sub query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm making statistic for 5 tables. I have made the example with one client data.

**loan**

```
id   | status
------------
1454 | payed
```

**payment schedule**

```
id   | loan_id | user_client_id
-----------------------------
1456 | 1454    | 3113
```

**payment_schedule_row**

```
id   | payment_schedule_id | payment | payment_date
---------------------------------------------------
5013 |  1456               |    32   | 2013-11-06
5014 |  1456               |    32   | 2013-12-06
5015 |  1456               |    32   | 2013-01-05
5016 |  1456               |    32   | 2013-02-04
5017 |  1456               |    32   | 2013-03-06
5018 |  1456               |    32   | 2013-04-05
5019 |  1456               |    32   | 2013-05-05
5020 |  1456               |    32   | 2013-06-04
5021 |  1456               |    32   | 2013-07-04
5022 |  1456               |    32   | 2013-08-03
5023 |  1456               |    32   | 2013-09-02
5014 |  1456               |    32   | 2013-10-02
```

**payment_schedule_cover**

```
id    | payment_schedule_id |    date    | sum
----------------------------------------------
2282  | 1456                | 2013-11-08 | 34
3054  | 1456                | 2013-12-07 | 40
3776  | 1456                | 2013-01-04 | 38
4871  | 1456                | 2013-02-06 | 49
5954  | 1456                | 2013-03-06 | 40
7070  | 1456                | 2013-04-25 | 49
9029  | 1456                | 2013-05-21 | 52
10377 | 1456                | 2013-06-20 | 30
10391 | 1456                | 2013-06-21 | 30
10927 | 1456                | 2013-07-07 | 60
```

**payment_schedule_delay**

```
id    | payment_schedule_row_id | start_date | end_date   | delay 
----------------------------------------------------------------
1135  | 5013                    | 2013-11-07 | 2013-11-08 | 0.07
1548  | 5014                    | 2013-12-07 | 2013-12-07 | 0.03
2628  | 5016                    | 2014-02-05 | 2014-02-06 | 0.01
```

And the query is :

```
SELECT period, loan_sum, covers, delay
FROM
    (SELECT MAX(EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM psc.date)) AS period, 
    (SELECT SUM(psr2.payment) FROM payment_schedule_row AS psr2 WHERE psr.payment_schedule_id = psr2.payment_schedule_id) AS loan_sum,
    (SELECT SUM(psc2.sum) FROM payment_schedule_cover AS psc2 WHERE psc.payment_schedule_id = psc2.payment_schedule_id) AS covers,
    (SELECT SUM(psd2.delay) FROM payment_schedule_delay AS psd2 WHERE psr.id = psd2.payment_schedule_row_id) AS delay
    FROM loan
    INNER JOIN payment_schedule AS ps ON ps.loan_id = loan.id
    INNER JOIN payment_schedule_row AS psr ON psr.payment_schedule_id = ps.id
    INNER JOIN payment_schedule_cover AS psc ON psc.payment_schedule_id = ps.id
    WHERE loan.status = 'payed'
    GROUP BY ps.id) AS sum_by_id
GROUP BY period
```

Result for the query:

```
period  | loan_sum  | covers | delay
-----------------------------------
201407  | 384       | 422    | 0.07
```

Everything is right except the delay. It should be 0.11 (0.07 + 0.03 + 0.01)

So I have been trying to find the error from the query for days now. Maybe someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

**Sqlfiddle link:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21585/2

Comment: get this in a sqlfiddle and post the link

Comment: try the below first though

Comment: Got the same result with your query. Ok I'm adding this to sqlfiddle in a hour.

Comment: Can you try changing this line? ````(SELECT SUM(psd2.delay) FROM payment_schedule_delay AS psd2 WHERE psr.id IN (psd2.payment_schedule_row_id))````

Comment: Soon as a fiddle is up this will be resolved pretty quick

Comment: Added sqlfiddle link to question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got an answer from a MySQL forum. The answer what fixed my problem was:

... there are problems ...

1. The Group By operator in the subquery does not see aggregation inside the correlated sub-subquery sums. Those sums need to be moved out a level.
2. There's no aggregation for the outer query's Group By to group; it just functions as an Order By
3. A query like select a,b,c sum(d) ... group by a can return arbitrary results for b and c unless a strictly 1:1 relationship holds between a and each of b and c, which looks unlikely to be the case in your subquery.
4. Correlated subqueries are inefficient, as yours illustrate with their two-stage joins
5. The `delay` correlated subquery doesn't join to anything

So move correlated subquery logic to the FROM clause, join the `delay` query, touch up the Group By clause, and we have ...

```
select psc.period, psc.sum, psr.payments, sum(psd.delay) as delay
from loan
join payment_schedule as ps on ps.loan_id = loan.id
join(
    select payment_schedule_id, sum(payment) as payments
    from payment_schedule_row
    group by payment_schedule_id
) as psr on psr.payment_schedule_id = ps.id
join (
    select payment_schedule_id, sum(sum) as sum, max( extract(year_month from date) ) as period
    from payment_schedule_cover
    group by payment_schedule_id
) psc on ps.id = psc.payment_schedule_id
join payment_schedule_row psr2 on ps.id = psr2.payment_schedule_id
join (
    select payment_schedule_row_id, sum(delay) as delay
    from payment_schedule_delay
    group by payment_schedule_row_id
) as psd on psr2.id = psd.payment_schedule_row_id
where loan.status = 'payed'
group by psc.period, psc.sum, psr.payments;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT period, loan_sum, covers, delay
FROM
    (SELECT MAX(EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM psc.date)) AS period, 
    (SELECT SUM(psr2.payment) FROM payment_schedule_row AS psr2 WHERE psr.payment_schedule_id = psr2.payment_schedule_id) AS loan_sum,
    (SELECT SUM(psc2.sum) FROM payment_schedule_cover AS psc2 WHERE psc.payment_schedule_id = psc2.payment_schedule_id) AS covers,
    (SELECT SUM(psd2.delay) FROM payment_schedule_delay AS psd2 WHERE psr.id = psd2.payment_schedule_row_id) AS delay
    FROM loan
    INNER JOIN payment_schedule AS ps ON ps.loan_id = loan.id
    INNER JOIN payment_schedule_row AS psr ON psr.payment_schedule_id = ps.id
    INNER JOIN payment_schedule_cover AS psc ON psc.payment_schedule_id = ps.id
    INNER JOIN payment_schedule_delay AS psd ON psr.id = psd.payment_schedule_row_id
    WHERE loan.status = 'payed'
    GROUP BY ps.id) AS sum_by_id
GROUP BY period
```

Comment: Still got the same result :( and the sqlfiddle doesn't seem to work right now. Outputs always the error: Unknown Error Occurred: Premature end of file.:

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT period, loan_sum, covers, delay
FROM
    (SELECT MAX(EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM psc.date)) AS period, 
    (SELECT SUM(psr2.payment) FROM payment_schedule_row AS psr2 WHERE psr.payment_schedule_id = psr2.payment_schedule_id) AS loan_sum,
    (SELECT SUM(psc2.sum) FROM payment_schedule_cover AS psc2 WHERE psc.payment_schedule_id = psc2.payment_schedule_id) AS covers,
    (SELECT SUM(psd2.delay) FROM payment_schedule_delay AS psd2 WHERE psr.id IN /* IN operator will allow for multiple values like psr.id IN (5013,5014,5016) */ psd2.payment_schedule_row_id) AS delay
    FROM loan
    INNER JOIN payment_schedule AS ps ON ps.loan_id = loan.id
    INNER JOIN payment_schedule_row AS psr ON psr.payment_schedule_id = ps.id
    INNER JOIN payment_schedule_cover AS psc ON psc.payment_schedule_id = ps.id
    WHERE loan.status = 'paid'
    GROUP BY ps.id) AS sum_by_id
GROUP BY period
```

Change `=` to `IN` in the line where you are summarizing the delay values.

Comment: Still got the same result :/